# Finding equation for Hyperbola, given 3 points.

Tags: geometry

> "A hyperbola passes through $(0,-1)$, $(2, -1.5)$ and $(-1, 0)$. Find its equation..."

How would I go working this out? Would the $x$ and $y$ asymp be $-1$?

*I dont just want an answer, coz I need to know how to do it*

Thanks.

Comment: Three points are not sufficient to uniquely determine a hyperbola; you need some additional information.  For example, if you were given that the asymptotes are parallel to the coordinate axes, then  you could proceed as in Claude Leibovici's answer.  If, instead, the axes of the hyperbola were parallel to the coordinate axes, the solution would be entirely different. And there are lots more hyperbolas through those three points, at all sorts of crazy angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from [this article](http://sarcasticresonance.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/how-many-points-does-it-take-to-define/) and [this random example I tried](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7Bx%5E2-y%5E2%3D1%2Cy%5E2-x%5E2%2F2%3D1%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-5%2C5%7D%2C%7By%2C-5%2C5%7D%5D), you would need at least $5$ distinct points to uniquely determine a hyperbola.

What I **can** tell you is that, because the slope between $(-1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$ is steeper than between $(0,-1)$ and $(2,-1.5)$, the hyperbola will probably take the form of $$\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2} = 1$$ where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the intersection of the asymptotes whose slopes are $\displaystyle \pm \frac{b}{a}$.

The circle is the only conic uniquely determined by $3$ different points. Everything else needs at least $5$. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7Bx%5E2%2F2%2By%5E2%3D1%2Cx%5E2%2By%5E2%2F2%3D1%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C3%7D%2C%7By%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D) and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7By%3Dx%5E2-2%2Cx%3Dy%5E2-2%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C3%7D%2C%7By%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D) and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7Bx%5E2-y%5E2%3D1%2Cy%5E2-x%5E2%2F2%3D1%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-5%2C5%7D%2C%7By%2C-5%2C5%7D%5D) as examples of why $4$ points is still not enough.

Comment: Does that fact that it is a reciprocal graph help?

Comment: You mean something like $\displaystyle y = \frac{1}{x}$ that may have shifted by some units in some direction?

Comment: Nah, its not one, sorry.

Comment: Aww man, I was gonna suggest $\displaystyle y+2 = \frac{2}{x+2}$.

Comment: Let me play with that, see what I can get.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: "You would only need three points if it were a parabola" *and* the parabola were in standard position, with its axis vertical (so it's given by $y=ax^2+bx+c$ for some $a,b,c$).  There are likely to be parabolas through these three points with axes in almost all directions.

Comment: @AndreasBlass - you're right. Sorry, the counterexample I just thought of never occurred to me while I was writing this. Let me edit that.

Comment: If it is given that the hyperbola is a rectangular hyperbola . Will that make it enough to uniquely define it with 3 points only ?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that the hyperbola is given in rectangular coordinates, that is to say under the form $$y=\frac{a+b x}{c+d x}$$  Because all coefficients appear in the general formula, fix any of them equal to $1$ without any lost of generality. Here, we shall arbitrarily fix $d=1$. So, we consider $$y=\frac{a+b x}{c+ x}$$ The curve goes through three data points you are given and we have the parameters $a,b,c$ to identify. This leads us with three equations for three unknowns; using you data points in the order you gave them, we so have $$ -1 =\frac{a}{c}$$  $$-\frac{3}{2}=\frac{a+2 b}{c+2}$$ $$0=\frac{a-b}{c-1}$$  From the first equation, we immediately have $a=-c$, from the third $b=a=-c$ and the second then gives $c=2$.

So the equation is $$y=\frac{-2x-2}{2+x}=-\frac{2 (x+1)}{x+2}$$ what you have to double check in order to verify that the solution is valid.

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: If your hyperbola is axis-oriented (like this form) and you know the asymptote (and it is a horizontal asymptote), you only need two additional points to solve. This answer helped me.