# Looking for a function to define a specific curve, given a single parameter

Tags: vector-analysis

The curve

1. passes through (0,0) and (1,1),
2. has an area under the curve from x=0 to x=1 that is equal to the parameter (such that a parameter of .5 returns the line `y=x`),
3. has a monotonic second derivative evaluated along the curve, and
4. is axisymmetric around `y=1-x`.

It would serve the same purpose if I had a function to define a similar curve that passed through (0,1) and (1,0), yielded the line `y=1-x` with the parameter of .5, and was axisymmetric around `y=x`.

I can find many (infinite, I suppose) functions that will define curves that meet `1` and `3`, of course. I am willing to optimize another parameter or two to approximate `2`, as actual equality is nice but not necessary, as is the simplicity of a single function rather than an optimization function and the curve function. `4` has me stumped, though.

Comment: Give an example of a non-trivial example function that is "axis symmetric around $y = 1-x$," regardless of the other constraints.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork For instance, $y = 1-\frac1x$ is axisymmetric around $y = 1-x$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I'm very willing to concede the non-existence thereof, I simply don't know. I'm a statistician who is well out of his depth in this particular problem!

Comment: Not something generalizable yet, but a bit of fiddling around with Desmos shows that $y = 1 + \phi - \frac{1}{1+\phi}$ meets 1, 3, and 4, but sadly not 2 (even though it looked like it might have).

Comment: Also, I should ask: are you looking for a full solutions, or just some hints?

Comment: @EricSnyder This is a small part of something I'm doing for work, but it's also one of two potential paths I'm going down and I've solved the other, so this is now just my curiosity (and desire for options).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to solve it:

[image]

Parameterize your function by an angle $\theta$ centered at $(0,1)$ (blue point), with $\theta = 0$ being downward, and $\theta = \pi/2$ being rightward.  Thus we only care about $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.  Moreover, we must have $r(0) = r(\pi/2) = 1$.

To ensure the difficult condition that the function is symmetric with respect to the dashed red line $y = 1-x$, we merely need to ensure that the radius function $r(\theta)$ is symmetric with respect to $\theta = \pi/4$.  (Think about it.)

One class of such functions is $r(\theta) = 1 + a \sin (2 \theta)$ for $a$ bounded by some small number.  (You can add more harmonic terms, or terms of the form $r(\theta) \propto (\theta - \pi/4)^2$ and such as you like, so long as you ensure the end conditions $r(0) = r(\pi/2) = 1$.)

Now express the $x$ and $y$ coordinates from an analysis of the basic coordinates:

$x(\theta) = r(\theta) \sin \theta$

$y(\theta) = 1 - r(\theta) \cos \theta$.

Now you merely need to use these to express $y(x;a)$ and you're done.

Of course once you have $y(x)$ you can find the stated area,

$$A = \int\limits_{x=0}^1 y(x;a)\ dx$$

and hence you can find $a(A)$.

Comment: I think there are some problems with this analysis. Consider that at $\alpha = 1$, the function $r(\theta)$ must be a sawtooth wave with $r(0^-)=1, r(0^+)=0$, while at $\alpha = 0$ we need a function that returns the hypotenuse of a triangle with one side of length $1$, and one side of length that you'd think would be the sine of the angle, but isn't due to our parametrization.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  First, there is no $\alpha$ in sight, and there is no way the parameterization gives a sawtooth in any case.  Mark the key points and state their coordinates.  That should help you figure out your error.

Comment: Apologies, I thought the OP had used $\alpha$ as the name of their parameter for some reason. With their parameter (which I'll call $\alpha$ for now so it has a name), if $\alpha = 1$, the area under the "curve" must be $1$--in other words, $y(\theta) = 1$ for all $\theta$ in your parametrization other than $\theta = 0$. I guess you're right that it's not a sawtooth, it's just a complete discontinuity. However, if we consider $\alpha = 0.999$, then $x(\theta) \approx 0$ for $0<\theta<\pi/4$, and $x(\theta) \approx x$ for $\pi/4<\theta<\pi/2$. With the converse for $y(\theta)$...

Comment: ... (character limit) I guess sawtooth is the wrong name for the function. $r(\theta)$ must drop rapidly from $1$ to $0+\delta$ in the range $0<\theta<(\pi/4 - \epsilon)$, then increase almost linearly from $0+\delta$ to $1$ in the range $(\pi/4 - \epsilon)< \theta<\pi/2$. So a graph of $r(\theta)$ plotted vs $\theta$ on Cartesian coordinates with $r(\theta) \to y$ and $\theta \to x$ would be $y \approx 0$ from $0$ to $\approx pi/4$, then a diagonal from $(\pi/4, 0)$ to $(\pi/2, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

All right, so after a bunch of trial and error analysis, I have something that gets most of your requirements, though the scaling on the area under the curve is wrong--I'll let you try to curve fit that if that part is truly necessary.

I figured a hyperbola with the x and y axes as asymptotes might be a good starting place, which led me to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/686740/585349) with some good info. [This Desmos sheet](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lxnn58srm2) shows you some of what I did.

Basically, the top equation using $q$ was a good starting point, but we needed $q = 0$ at $a = 1$, and $q = -1$ at $a = 0$, but also $q = \infty$ at $a = 0.5$ so that we would end up with our line. There's a discontinuity at $a = 0.5, x = 0.5$, but it's not bad.

The rest of the sheet is working out a symmetrical hyperbola for q. Then Wolfram Aplha got me to the final equation:

$$ y\ =\ \frac{\ (2a^{2}-3a)\ x}{\left(2a^{2}-a-1\right)+\left(1-2a\right)x}\  $$

As mentioned, the area under the curve doesn't fit what you want. You could likely map $\alpha$ to a curve-fit function $f(\alpha) = \beta$ to get that.

Hope this helps. Interesting problem.